# Creating new data frame from old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe having only those rows which has name in the `Image_list`. Original `df` has records more than 200,000 whereas `Image_list` has only 300 list of image names.

```
for name in Image_list:
    df1= df.loc[df['ID']== name]
    print(df1)
    Final_data.append(df1)

Final_data.shape
```

'ID' column contains much more than `Image_list`, for example

```
['Black_Hair',
 'Eyeglasses',
 'Male',
 'Smiling',
 'Straight_Hair',
 'Wearing_Earrings',
 'Wearing_Necktie']
```

Comment: should use `df1= df[df['ID']==name]`

Comment: changes but data is not being copied in new dataframe

Comment: and need to assign the new data: `Final_data = Final_data.append(df1)`

Comment: Also, should use `pd.concat()` instead of `df.append()`, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to assign the new data to the existing df `Final_data`. Also, the method `df.append()` is deprecated. Should use `pd.concat()` instead

```
import pandas as pd

Final_data = pd.DataFrame()

for name in Image_list:
    df1 = df[df['ID']==name]
    print(df1.shape)
    Final_data = pd.concat([Final_data, df1])

print(Final_data.shape)
```